# Do I have to load Zend Apache/PHP extensions if I'm not using Zend Framework?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, zend

I'm configuring web server. I want to remove any unnecessary extensions etc.

I'm not using Zend Framework and I will never use it on this server.

When I check configuration (by using `phpinfo()`) I see, that Apache is loading some extensions related with Zend.

Do I need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phpinfo does not show you what Apache loaded, it shows you what PHP loaded. You probably need the the things you are talking about - hint: next time list the specific items in your question. On a current PHP installation you will likely have the Zend engine and the Zend opcode cache. You can't run PHP without the former, and while it will work without the latter, in the absence of an opcode cache, performance will be very poor.

You could always experiment with different configurations.